# Parallel.Foreach - last item waits for other items

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I've written a parellel.foreach, but the last iteration allways waits for execution before all other items have been processed, in this case, number 10 fires only when 1-9 are ready, tried it a couple of times, why is that and can i fix that?

here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Min = 100;
        int Max = 200;
        Random randNum = new Random();
        int[] test2 = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10).Select(i => randNum.Next(Min, Max)).ToArray();
        string[] result = test2.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
        int count = 0;
        var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 };
        Parallel.ForEach(result, options, rec =>
        {
            count++;
            go(count);
        });
        Console.WriteLine("Ready!");
        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }

    public static void go(int counter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("START: " + counter.ToString());
        Thread.Sleep(3500);
        Console.WriteLine("END: " + counter.ToString());
    }
}
```

***EDIT***
I ran the program for 20-30 times and it seems that a few times 10 is started before 9 ended. I think this happens in about 4 or 5 percent of the times. It's (working properly) happening some sort of random. because it works sometimes it feels a bit buggy, but not a big issue for the performance of my application which i'm building. You understand the above was a testcase, not a part of the actual project :)

Comment: `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4`, so you'll only have 4 threads to perform 10 tasks. Do you expect the tasks to be ordered at random?

Comment: yes, in this case 4 threads at a time, order isn't a issue and honestly I don't care which ordering is used :) ).

Point is that number 10 is only fired when 1-9 are ready, I don't get that why that's happening

Comment: It doesn't seem to happen with a different number of calls, e.g. if you change it to `Enumerable.Repeat(0, 13)` or if you change `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to 5.

Comment: @Mario I'm consistently seeing #10 not being started until #9 finishes (I simplified `go()` so that it just always sleeps for 4 seconds, I changed `count++` to InterlockedIncrement instead to make it threadsafe like so: `go(rec, Interlocked.Increment(ref count));`

Comment: @Matthew: you are right, when I  try to run the program for a dozen times, the program waits executing number 10 before 1-9 are ready (removed my 'answer' from the start thread, because i couldn't reproduce it anymore)

Comment: @Mario Yes, I'm fairly convinced you've discovered a strange effect here. Hopefully an expert will have an idea about this. :) BTW it's much easier to see the effect if you simplify `go()` to have just the first and last `WriteLine()` calls with a `Thread.Sleep(4000)` inbetween.

Comment: When I change the `Repeat(0,10)` to `Repeat(0,9)` it keeps working fine. Frustrating not getting the grip on it

Comment: @MatthewWatson You are right, I will simplify the example. But the number is easier for seeing which iteration is being processed.

Comment: It looks like either the scheduler is pre-assigning work items to threads, or perhaps the scheduler is killing a thread when the number of active threads is less than the number of remaining work items. I wonder if the `Sleep` causes this. Do you see the same behavior if you replace the `Sleep` with code that actually does real work?

Comment: grrrr ... I meant when the number of active threads is MORE THAN the number of remaining work items.